# Keep JVM running with a JAR from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar, jvm

I'm running the closure templates compiler on a soy file using a watch - it just runs

```
java -jar SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar  --outputPathFormat simple.js   simple.soy
```

every time the file changes.

The problem is that it takes a long time for the jar to load up each for each run. Is there an easy way (easy=command line tool) that would keep the JVM running to make each run faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Nailgun
http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple class that calls SoyToJsSrcCompiler's main method passing the args taken from System.in.

Something like this (not tested) (enter "quit" to exit the application):

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter command (eg: --outputPathFormat simple.js   simple.soy): ");
      String line = br.readLine();
      if (line.equals("quit"))
        break;

      com.google.template.soy.SoyToJsSrcCompiler.main(line.split(" +"));
    }    
  }
```

And execute your launcher withouth arguments:

```
java -cp MyLauncher.jar:SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar launcher.MyLauncher
```